# SignalR Core with Generic Host

Tags: c#, .net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

Is it possible to use SignalR Core with a Generic Host? If yes, how can I do that?

Right now, it is a .NET Core 2.2 project, although I can also upgrade it to .NET Core 3.0 (preview), if that would be necessary.

Example Generic Host:

```cs
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
   var host = new HostBuilder()
      .Build(); 

   await host.RunAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of now, you have to use WebHost only to host signalR on asp.net core. See below discussion link from github.

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5284

However, it is possible to run signalr on Genric Host when Project bedrock comes into .net framework. See the sample code provided by david in the below link.

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4772

here is the sameple application created brady for running signalr on .net core background service. However, internally it uses WebHost only.

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/signalr/background-service/sample